# Execv with arguments starting from second element

Tags: c, system-calls, argv, execv

I am making a program that can take another program as an argument and run it.

I am using `execv()` to run the second program, but how can I use `argv[]` (that comes from the main program, is a `char*`) as arguments for `execv()`?

The first element of `argv[]` is the name of the main program, so I need to start at the second element where the name of the next program is located.

I am thinking there might be different solutions, for example:

- Tell `execv()` to start from the second argument
- copy the content of `argv[]` (except first element) to another array and use that
- Something with pointers so maybe I can point to the second element and start there

What is the best way to do this?
And can I get an example of how to do it?

Comment: argv+1 using the magic of pointer arithmetic

Comment: Use a variation on `execv(argv[1], &argv[1])` — more or less your first option, though it's not really clear how that differs from the third.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the `argv` is actually a pointer to array of pointers. The more correct way to define it would be `char **argv`.

Defining it as `*argv[]` is just a syntactic sugar.  So your third guess is a best one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(int array_size, char **array) {
    for(int i=0; i<array_size; i++) {
        printf("\t%s\n", array[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char **argv_new = argv+1;

    printf("argv:\n");
    print_array(argc, argv);
    printf("argv_new:\n");
    print_array(argc-1, argv_new);
    return 0;
}
```

You can also play with interchanging function arguments `char **argv` vs `char *argv[]` and you wont see a difference.
But code like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *argv_new[] = argv+1;
```

will give you an error - of invalid type conversion. That is due to a fact that defining an array on a stack requires to know the size of array during the compilation. But defining array as a function parameter - does not, the compiler in that case presumes that the stack manipulation is done in the caller function.